# JQuery style dom manipulation in C#

Tags: c#, html, dom, html-parsing

I'm trying to perform some DOM manipulation, mainly selection of all child elements of a parent element such as a `div` of `id=...` or `class=...`. Is there some lightweight method of doing this?

Comment: Is your code running on the server or client (ASP.NET or Silverlight)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) is probably your best bet.

The syntax isn't as nicely fluent as jQuery, but it's pretty good.

Answer (score 4):

Try this project, I'm using it in a web crawler of mine.

https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this server side, then HTML Agility Pack is your best bet. For client side you can use [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). For example `$('#id > *')` will get all children of an element with an `id="id"` or `$('.class > *')` for classes.